# PHP doesn't works after decoding

Tags: php

Trying to decode some php script. But have some troubles. Php obfuscated with 2 encoders. One if it is ioncube, and can't detect second. And after decoding ioncube, it totally not working. And calls function, which we don't have at all.

```
    {
    $this->{$this->kbm1("spa2")} = $_obfuscated_0D2610332B303C270C3F3C2732385B090A352D18062D01_;
    $_obfuscated_0D3F16240D2F1910091E09062910140C1D11361C331F11_ = _obfuscated_0D290C27360D15262B380E1A29251D31281404340C0601_($this->kbm1("ofb7"), _obfuscated_0D3D5C3D02351C153B273D31260D092D3403390C0E1622_($this->kbm1("ofb8")));
    $this->{$this->kbm1("spa4")} = _obfuscated_0D012C5B0B23041A5C3130143C18233D051404151E3932_($_obfuscated_0D3F16240D2F1910091E09062910140C1D11361C331F11_[$this->kbm1("ofb9")] . $_obfuscated_0D3F16240D2F1910091E09062910140C1D11361C331F11_[$this->kbm1("jzm0")] . $_obfuscated_0D3F16240D2F1910091E09062910140C1D11361C331F11_[$this->kbm1("jzm1")] . $this->kbm1("ofb7") . (isset($_obfuscated_0D3F16240D2F1910091E09062910140C1D11361C331F11_[$this->kbm1("jzm2")]) ? $_obfuscated_0D3F16240D2F1910091E09062910140C1D11361C331F11_[$this->kbm1("jzm2")] : $this->kbm1("ofb9")));
    $_obfuscated_0D03401D0B342E240D0C1D3111292637381C0C09130132_ = (int) _obfuscated_0D3201352C0E1836213F2D5C2F3507123E161E2F061B01_($this->kbm1("jzm4"), _obfuscated_0D04191D1403281330263F125B1E0D17330A1A18102C22_()) % $this->kbm1("jzm5") == $this->kbm1("ofb9");
    if (!$this->{$this}->kbm1("jzm7")(!$_obfuscated_0D03401D0B342E240D0C1D3111292637381C0C09130132_)) {
        $this->{$this}->kbm1("jzm9")();
    }
}
private function ulg6($obg9)
{
    if (!isset($_obfuscated_0D34060702361D26363F1505130A09091C40023D0F2B11_[$_obfuscated_0D35093404093924061F01263B3D0226171207363F1022_])) {
        $_obfuscated_0D34060702361D26363F1505130A09091C40023D0F2B11_[$_obfuscated_0D35093404093924061F01263B3D0226171207363F1022_] = [];
        $_obfuscated_0D283E2F11103706320239332E122817223E2E25101401_ = $this->{$this->kbm1("pfb7")}->{$this}->kbm1("dpu3")($this->kbm1("ulg9") . _obfuscated_0D3D5C3D02351C153B273D31260D092D3403390C0E1622_($this->kbm1("pfb9")) . $this->kbm1("dut0") . (int) $_obfuscated_0D35093404093924061F01263B3D0226171207363F1022_ . $this->kbm1("dut1") . (int) $this->{$this->kbm1("uvi1")}->{$this}->kbm1("ofb2")($this->kbm1("pnx9")) . $this->kbm1("ulg2"));
        foreach ($_obfuscated_0D283E2F11103706320239332E122817223E2E25101401_->{$this->kbm1("ulg3")} as $_obfuscated_0D01303826350E1E03212F3830041A2214180C072E0311_) {
            $_obfuscated_0D34060702361D26363F1505130A09091C40023D0F2B11_[$_obfuscated_0D35093404093924061F01263B3D0226171207363F1022_][$_obfuscated_0D01303826350E1E03212F3830041A2214180C072E0311_[$this->kbm1("dut2")]] = _obfuscated_0D2E1D32253E0C3029013C38112D243F29073C291E2D11_($_obfuscated_0D01303826350E1E03212F3830041A2214180C072E0311_[$this->kbm1("rpg0")]);
        }
    }
    return $_obfuscated_0D34060702361D26363F1505130A09091C40023D0F2B11_[$_obfuscated_0D35093404093924061F01263B3D0226171207363F1022_];
}
```

Part of code. Does someone knows which obfuscastor is it?

Comment: There's probably no way to get it back because the variable names aren't stored.

Answer (score 0):

I was exploring through your post and I found it.
See More [From Here](https://gist.github.com/n3o77/4665748)

```
$string = "BASE 64 STRING";
$decode = strrev('edoced_46esab');

$result = eval(str_replace('eval', 'return', $decode($string)));
while (strstr($result, 'eval')) {
     $result = eval(str_replace('eval', 'return', $result));
}

echo("<pre>".$result."</pre>");
```

Also, I assume you try some online decode. Here some lists:

1. [glot.io](https://glot.io/snippets/ets16ruv2v)
2. [jonhburn2](http://jonhburn2.freehostia.com/decode/)
3. [unphp.net](https://www.unphp.net/)

I hope it will help you